# Is it possible for Emacs to run a Matlab shell that is located on a remote server?

Tags: emacs, matlab

I would like to be able to use Matlab-mode (matlab.el) to run a matlab shell. The only problem is, Matlab is located on a remote host. Is this even possible? If so, please explain. I'm currently playing around with tramp but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll try these proposed solution out.

Comment: is emacs running locally and matlab remotely? if that's the case, no need for tramp, see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried using the emacs matlab mode through ssh, no problem

had to make a script which loads matlab, couldn't just specify the command in matlab.el

so:

/home/second/remoteMatlab:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh orac matlab -nodisplay
```

where orac is the host which has matlab. you can pass commands to ssh here. i use ssh config and key authentication so only need the hostname here

in matlab.el, find

```
    (defcustom matlab-shell-command
```

and set to eg

```
(defcustom matlab-shell-command "/home/second/remoteMatlab"
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The bash file works but when I try to use matlab via the menu. I see it tries to run matlab and not the specified path"

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are doing, but this seems possible.  If
you use Tramp (or sshfs, my personal choice) to edit a script on a
remote machine, you will be able to run it on that remote machine.  If
you have a `*shell*` buffer open, it can easily be ssh'd to that remote
machine.  If you are doing something REPL-like where emacs sends input
to this buffer that's connected to a process over ssh, it should still
work.  If it is communicating with a remote process over a socket, you
can use ssh forwarding to make the socket appear local.

Anyway, there is not much gap between local and remote, so this should
all work out.

Finally, to toe the (GNU) party line... have you tried Octave running locally?

Answer (score 1):

@Yotham : I can't comment yet on earlier answers, but your problem (Script working, malab-shell command in emacs not) may be due to the fact  that you didn't delete/rename your matlab.elc file?

This way emacs never gets to know of the change since it prefers .elc over .el files for speed.

Resolved the same issue for me.

cheers
tnt