# Start a remote Matlab process within Emacs matlab-mode?

Tags: matlab, emacs, ssh

I use Matlab remotely via ssh, and would like to execute regions of code from an m-file in Emacs without having to cut and paste. How do I configure Emacs to do this?

I tried to follow the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133498/is-it-possible-for-emacs-to-run-a-matlab-shell-that-is-located-on-a-remote-serve): I wrote a script that connects to the server and opens Matlab. The script works when I run it in a terminal. I edited matlab.el as explained on that page. Now, if I'm editing my m-file in Emacs and try to start Matlab, I get a message that it can't execute my remoteMatlab.sh file, and that M-shell exited abnormally with code 1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could it be that your remote machine is on windows?

Comment: The remote machine is on Linux.

Comment: hmmm... then it *should* just work. maybe try in addition the switch `-nodesktop`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this running a shell from within emacs, starting up your ssh and matlab session in it, and renaming the shell buffer from   `*term*` or whatever to   `*MATLAB*`. You can then use matlab-mode on a script file and run the code.

Answer (score -2):

This is not exactly what you asked for but may achieve the same thing. You can use function dbstop, which allows you to set debug break points through code.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dbstop.html#inputarg_location